# What kind of data does AudioRecord read from Android system?

Tags: android, audiorecord

In Android system, ” AudioRecord” could get a sound signal into an array, and the code is:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
int r = mAudioRecord.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

We need to confirm that which exactly is the type of the data, Is it the pressure of the sound, the voltage of the sound or the intensity of sound? In another word, the unit of the data should be Pascal (Pa), Volt (V) or Decibel (Db)?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In link explain basic http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(byte[], int, int)
"""Reads audio data from the audio hardware for recording into a byte array. The format specified in the AudioRecord constructor should be ENCODING_PCM_8BIT to correspond to the data in the array.

ENCODING_PCM_8BIT
Audio data format: PCM 8 bit per sample."""

Comment: Oh oh, a year has passed. Tks a lot :D